# Using JSONP in react-redux application

Tags: reactjs, http-headers, cors, jsonp

I am just trying to get the `CORS headers` issue caused by `missing headers` in request out of the way and hence inclined to using `JSONP`.

Any suggestions/ideas how to use `JSONP` in a `react-redux` app? Like how to configure and use it?

Answer (score 0):

In your react component, dispatch an action that is caught by middleware. The middleware should make a call to the jsonp endpoint, probably using jquery's $.ajax method. I also like the [fetchJsonp](https://github.com/camsong/fetch-jsonp) library. Your middleware should then dispatch a new action with the data received by ajax or fetchJsonp, which should be caught by your reducer, and alter the state.

Answer (score 0):

I use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) in most of cases in react apps:

```
    // payload is your post data
    const payload = {data: 'test'};
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      cors: true, // allow cross-origin HTTP request
      credentials: 'same-origin' // This is similar to XHR’s withCredentials flag
    };

    // SEND REQUEST
    fetch('http://example.com/', options).then((response) => {
      // TODO
    }).catch((error) => {
      // TODO
    });
```